# Getting only the last value while iterating over object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have an object something below in the code. but while iterating over the object i get only the last value. I cannot understand what i am doing wrong here !

```
var index = {};
var demoObj = [{
         0:{obj1: {...}, obj2: {...}, obj3: {...}}
     },
     {
         1:{obj1: {...}, obj2: {...}, obj3: {...}}
     }];

for (var i = 1; i <= demoObj.length; ++i) {
    index[i] = demoObj[i] ;
}

console.log(index);
```

Comment: Try using `index` instead of `Index` in your for loop and console.log.  Also you're declaring `index` as an object instead of an array.

Comment: i get second iterated value as undefined @evolutionxbox

Comment: You are also starting your loop at 1 and ending at 1 when you need to start at 0. So 1 will only be returned regardless.

Comment: What are your expected results?

Comment: By the way, `demoObj` is NOT an object. It is an array containing 2 objects.

Comment: Perhaps you should state the goal of your code as well. If you want to copy all properties of one object into another you can use `Object.assign()`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are skipping index 0

```
for (var i = 1; i <= demoObj.length; ++i) {
```

change to this

```
for (var i = 0; i <= demoObj.length; ++i) {
```

Comment: …and also iterating the non-existing index `2`.

Comment: oh ... understood !

Answer (score -1):

You are logging your value after the for loop is done, try logging it inside the for loop.

And also variables are lowercase ;)

```
for (var i = 1; i <= demoObj.length; ++i) {
  index[ i ] = demoObj[i] ;
  console.log(Index);
}
```

Comment: why would this help?

Comment: everytime your i counts up (each loop) your value changes. When you're trying to get the value after the loop is done, it will always be the last one

Comment: That is not true when it is object or array